# Number appearing in Perl-generated JavaScript code instead of "$("

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl

On a site I'm working on there are random numbers appearing in a very simple bit of jQuery.

Instead of what's meant to appear, these numbers — `48`, etc. — appear at the beginning. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    48 48document).ready(function () {
    48 48".closed").click(function () {         
        48 48this).find("div.but").toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');           
             48 48this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');    
        });    
    });        
</script>
```

I can't even begin to imagine why it would spit this out when I hard-coded it into the site and there's no external file or anything.

OK, so since it's Perl I need to escape `$(`, but how? I took a look at the Perl documentation and I just felt like I'd been punched.

Do I just use single quotes instead of double quotes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.closed').click(function () {          
        $(this).find('div.but').toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');
        $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');    
      });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the full Perl script. It's the header of a site.

```
###########################
## META DATA AND HEADERS ##
###########################

$be_strict = 0;    # 1 = 404 on page not found
if ((!$title{$loadpage} || !$h1{$loadpage} || !$description{$loadpage} || !$keywords{$loadpage} || !$breadcrumb{$loadpage}) && $be_strict) {
  print "Status: 302 Found\r\n" .
      "Location: http://www.realots.co/404/\r\n" .
      "\r\n";
  exit(0);
} 

if ($action) {

  #############################
  ## Highscore page SEO Hack ##
  #############################

  if ($action eq "fish") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Fishing Skill</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Fishing Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Fishing Skill";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Fishing Skill Highscore list of our RealOTS. Check out these amazing fishermen!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,fishing,top fishing";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "ml") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Magic Level</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Magic Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Magic Level";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Magic Level Highscore list of our RealOTS. Check out these fearsome mages!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,magic,top magic";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "sword") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Sword Fighting</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Sword Fighting Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Sword Fighters";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Sword Fighting Highscore list of our RealOTS. Fear the mighty sword wielder!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,sword,top sword";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "axe") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Axe Fighting</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Axe Fighting Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Axe Fighters";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Axe Fighting Highscore list of our RealOTS. Behold these savage beasts with their amazing axe skills!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,axe,top axe,axe fighting";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "club") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Club Fighting</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Club Fighting Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Club Fighters";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Club Fighting Highscore list of our RealOTS. Caveman-like agility all around!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,club,top club,club fighting";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "dist") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Distance Fighting</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Distance Fighting Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Distance Fighters";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Distance Fighting Highscore list of our RealOTS. Death from afar, raining from the sky!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,distance,top distance,distance fighting";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "shield") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Shielding</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Shielding Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Shielding";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Shielding Highscore list of our RealOTS. These tanks are able to withstand tremendeous blows!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,shielding,top shielding";
  }
  elsif ($action eq "fist") {
    $breadcrumb{'highscores'}     = "<a href='/'>RealOTS</a> &raquo; <a href='/highscores/'>Highscores</a> &raquo; <b>Fist Fighting</b>";
    $h1{'highscores'}             = "RealOTS Fist Fighting Highscores";
    $title{'highscores'}          = "RealOTS Top Fist Fighters";
    $description{'highscores'}    = "Fist Fighting Highscore list of our RealOTS. They had special training by sensai Chuck Norris!";
    $keywords{'highscores'}       = "realots,otserv,tibia,highscore,hiscores,fist,top fist,fist fighting";
  }
}

#&print_header();
$web_content .= qq{
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <title>$title{$loadpage}</title>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Z97W94Kp7MlIOgiaMAYcFA4Lp4i5hckXdncRarXkBxk" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="I5HTpL8jLRcdrWk3jD83qIFDBkS4G_rmWHlxEq94jLU" />
    <style type="text/css">
      table.outlined {
        border-width: 1px;
        order-style: solid;
        border-color: #9999CC;
        border-collapse: separate;
      }
      a.suggestions:visited{color:#0000FF;text-decoration:none;}
      a.suggestions:link{color:#0000FF;text-decoration:none;}
      a.suggestions:hover{color:#305997;text-decoration:none;}

.trans {
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
}

    </style>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
body { overflow-y: auto; }
img#bg { position:absolute; z-index:-1; }
#content { position:static; }
</style>
<![endif]-->

};

if ($no_index{$loadpage}) {
  $web_content .= qq{    <meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE,NOSNIPPET" />};
} else {
  $web_content .= qq{    <meta name="Robots" content="index,follow" />};
}

$web_content .= qq{
    <meta name="keywords" content="$keywords{$loadpage}">
    <meta name="description" content="$description{$loadpage}">
    <meta name="author" content="RealOTS" />
    <meta name="Expires" content="never" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/images/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mollie.nl/partners/js/96481.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".closed").click(function () {


        $(this).find("div.but").toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');

         $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');

    });

});

    </script>




  </head>
};
```

Comment: somebody is replacing `$(` with `48 48`

Comment: Do you have server-side code that processes this file?

Comment: i don't know why this happens but you can try jQuery( instead of $( or vice-versa

Comment: try with jQuery( instead of $( ,  sometimes i got that trouble in my case all < > and & symbol will be replace with no reason JSF2.0 + Liferay + icefaces

Comment: The only non-funny-business suggestion I can fathom is a character-encoding/platform mismatch. Is 48 the only number that appears?

Comment: @user1487380 There is definitely a reason.

Comment: it's a perl script, I thought it may have something to do with meta charsets or something

Comment: Do you generating scripting code?

Comment: URL encoded characters: `%48 = H` ; HTML entities reference: `&#48; = 0` something is really wrong ;)

Comment: Indeed roxon, something is very wrong!

This isn't a site I built, it's just some code I inherited and am working on for a friend

Comment: It sounds like an encoding issue - some weird copy/paste into the file perhaps, or the server is sending the wrong header in the response?

Comment: the server is sending the correct header, everything works as it should apart from this bit of jquery.

Comment: It's worth noting that `$(` is a predefined variable in Perl. If it's unescaped on the script side, it'll be expanded into the process's group ID.

Comment: (which is a space-separated list of numbers, which may repeat. "48 48", for instance)

Comment: @PaulRoub instead write an answer **☻** Must be that.

Comment: ah, I've never written any perl before, since I figured I could just edit the javascript and html maybe I've made a mistake doing that...

Comment: This is an INTERESTING question. Why on earth aren't people upvoting? More twists than an M. Night Shyamalan film.

Comment: Can we see some of the actual Perl code? Replacing " with ' in the Javascript won't help, the changes need to happen at the Perl level.

Comment: Sure, I'll paste the full perl script, hang on.

Comment: ohhhh noooo who wrote that script? Don't Repeat Your Self (DRY)

Comment: Don't build JS with server side code, you're simply asking for trouble.

Comment: Please ***always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. It's the least you could do before asking others for help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`$(` is a Perl predefined variable, expanding to the process's group ID list.

> If you are on a machine that supports membership in multiple groups simultaneously, gives a space separated list of groups you are in. The first number is the one returned by getgid() , and the subsequent ones by getgroups() , one of which may be the same as the first number.

See the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24() docs for details.

To avoid the problem, make sure to escape `$(` (and any other JavaScript `$` chars) in Perl strings, or use `''` instead of `""` to avoid interpolation.

Bad:

```
$html = "$(document).ready(...)";
```

Good:

```
$html = "\$(document).ready(...)";
$html = '$(document).ready(...)';
```

In the code above, for example, the script section should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  \$(document).ready(function () {
    \$(".closed").click(function () {

      \$(this).find("div.but").toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');
      \$(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');

    });    
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Paul's escaping suggestions above, I prefer to use the alternate quoting method  you used above so I don't have to escape every string and quote in my Javascript. Enclosing a string in q{} will save you from having to escape every dollar sign. So long as you don't need interpolation in that block you'll be fine!

So your code could be written as:

```
$web_content .= q{
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".closed").click(function () {


             $(this).find("div.but").toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus');

             $(this).toggleClass('closed').toggleClass('open');

        });

    });

    </script>
};
```

Comment: Or use a non-interpolating heredoc: `$web_content .= <<'SCRIPT';`

Answer (score 8):

since you are generating the code via Perl, `$(` is a reserved one in Perl. Put it in a variable in give a string concatenation.

**Documentation**

> Since Perl 5.6, Perl variable names may be alphanumeric strings that begin with control characters (or better yet, a caret). These variables must be written in the form ${^Foo} ; the braces are not optional. ${^Foo} denotes the scalar variable whose name is a control-F followed by two o 's. These variables are reserved for future special uses by Perl, except for the ones that begin with ^_ (control-underscore or caret-underscore). No control-character name that begins with ^_ will acquire a special meaning in any future version of Perl; such names may therefore be used safely in programs. $^_ itself, however, is reserved.

**Solution**

Use either of these:

```
"\$(document).ready(...)";
'$(document).ready(...)';
```

Comment: I've never written perl before! I have no idea how to do that, I figured I could just edit stuff in the head without messing with the perl script.